# SubCode=40000. DataLakeFolderPath

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

when trying to configure Event Hubs Capture with Datalake Store, I get the following error in the Azure portal.

SubCode=40000. DataLakeFolderPath. + some tracking number guid and correlation guid.

[image]

Anyone know what this error means?

I assume it's got something to do with the DataLakeFolderPath, but no clue what SubCode of 40000 means.

Answer (score 3):

After redoing all the steps contained in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-archive-eventhub-capture) it seems to work.

If I retrace my steps it appears the error is likely due to me not setting the correct permissions at the ADLS root level, or the correct permissions at the specific Folder level.

I don't know which one, yet.

Comment: Any update on this? I get a similar error when deploying from script even though I assign all the permissions described in the article. "Failed to access provided Data Lake path. Please ensure the path exists and assigned with required access permissions."